# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "korrekt" und "zulässig"?

Tags: meaning, difference

In einer Antwort zu dieser [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2906/are-sentences-such-as-wir-waren-essen-grammatically-correct), wird

> Wir waren essen.

als **nicht korrekt** aber **zulässig** bezeichnet.

Worin besteht der Unterschied zwischen **korrekt** und **zulässig**?

**Edit:**

Dürfen Deutschlehrer das als Fehler markieren oder nicht?

Comment: Ey, deine Frage ist voll zulässig, Alter! ;) In der Mathematik würde man wohl analog sagen, dass "der Lösungsweg korrekt ist", zulässig, wenn er zum gleichen Ergebnis kommt aber nicht der allgemeinen Norm entspricht, was Zeichensymbolik und typ. Vorgehen beim Lösen eines math. Problems entspricht, aber dennoch widerspruchsfrei ist. Ich fürchte aber allg. verbindliche Unterschiede zwishcen den beiden Worten für jeden x-beliebigen Kontext wirst du kaum finden, da korrekt ein objektives Urteil ist, zulässig eher eine intersubjektive Konvention, Unterschied zw. einem Apfel und ner Birne ;)

Comment: Die Antwort ist doch: " [...]sind nicht korrect aber **umgangssprachlich** [...] zulässig.

Comment: Wie Gigili schon sagte: Die Frage ist falsch gestellt.

Answer (score 2):

Der Unterschied ist hat mit der grammatikalischen Korrektheit zu tun.

Grammatikalisch sollte es heißen 'Wir aßen' oder 'Wir waren beim Essen'. Allerdings ist es umgangssprachlich sehr verbreitet zu sagen 'Wir waren essen'. Grammatikalisch ist das nicht korrekt, da es keine zwei unabhängigen Verben im gleichen Satz(teil) geben kann. Da diese Satzkonstruktion aber im normalen Sprachgebrauch benutzt wird, ist sie zulässig. (Obwohl, in meiner Kindheit wurden wir verbessert, es war also zu dieser Zeit nicht zulässig.)

Comment: Die Verben sind nicht unabhängig, da "essen" als Infinitiv zu "waren" steht; es ist ein in die Vergangenheit transponierter freier "finaler" Infinitiv, wobei die Gegenwartsform "wir sind essen" lautet. Gerade die grammatische Form ist also korrekt, die Wortwahl allerdings umgangssprachlich.

Answer (score 1):

Im allgemeinen gibt es keinen Unterschied.

Es kann Situationen geben, in denen eine Sache optional ist, aber nicht notwendig - dann passt es eher zu sagen, es sei zulässig, als korrekt, insbes. wenn man ausdrücken will, dass es, obwohl zulässig, unerwünscht ist.

> Bei der Lösung von Aufgabe 7 ist die Verwendung eines Taschenrechners zulässig.

Ein *korrekt* könnte hier als Ermunterung aufgefaßt werden.

Comment: +1 Trotzdem interessant wie in dieser Antwort der Blick an der Tatsache, dass **jemand** den Gebrauch von Taschenrechnern zugelassen hat, abgewendet wird.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht ob ich Deinen Kommentar richtig verstehe wenn ich entgegne: Beide Ausdrücke setzen eine Norm voraus, der entsprochen wird, aber das `zulässig` klingt für mich einen Deut formaler. In der Bewertung von Alltagssprache würde ich eher `korrekt` verwenden, weil es keine Instanz gibt, die etwas als zulässig akzeptiert oder als nicht zulässig verwirft. "Dass Babies auch in der Mittagspause schreien ist zulässig" urteilte der Gerichtshof - als `korrekt` würde ich es nicht bezeichnen, weil es ja keine positive Norm gibt, die sagt, dass die Kinder schreien **sollen**.

Answer (score 1):

"Korrekt" refers to "richtig" and is a stricter standard than "zulassig" or "erlaubt." The latter two mean "ok," there's nothing considered "wrong" about them, but they are not 100 per cent "right" either.

Answer (score -1):

Ich nehme an du beziehst dich auf:

> `"wir waren essen" or "er ist telefonieren"` sind nicht **korrekt**, aber
>   umgangssprachlich (auch schriftlich) bedingt durch ihre weite
>   Verbreitung **zulässig**. `"wir aßen" und "er telefoniert"` sind korrekt.
>   Keine Unterschiede in der Bedeutung.

Das witzige an Sprache ist, alles ist zulässig und somit ist auch alles korrekt.

Ehe es den Duden bzw. eine einheitliche Rechtschreibung (vor der Lutherbibel) gab, gab es verschiedene Schreibweisen in Deutschland. Mit dem Resultat, das die innerdeutsche Kommunikation erschwert war. [Wikipedia - Deutsche Rechtschreibung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Rechtschreibung#Vom_Mittelalter_bis_zum_18._Jahrhundert)

Nur weil wir jetzt eine offizielle Deutsche Rechtschreibung haben, bedeutet das nicht, das sich die Sprache nicht weiterentwickelt.

Somit:

**Zulässig:** ist alles.

**Korrekt:** kommt drauf an nach welchem Regelwerk man die Korrektheit beurteilt.

Comment: Es gibt durchaus einen Bedeutungsunterschied zu "wir aßen", denn "wir waren essen" verstehe ich stets als (auswärts) essen gehen: "Was hast du um 12 gemacht?" - "Ich habe gegessen" -- "Wo warst du um 12?" - "Ich war (z.B. in der Kantine) essen" oder "Ich war die ganze Zeit an meinem Schreibtisch und habe nur zwischendurch in meine Stullen gebissen ..."